# gcc use wrong command

Tags: python, gcc, pip

I install *pycryptodomex*, is a C-base python library. When install processing run into C build step. It throws a error.

```
running build_ext
warning: no support for Intel AESNI instructions
building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
/home/luanvv/Source/capcloud_01/30_implementation/31_source/CapCloudCommon/src/net/ -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DLTC_NO_ASM -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/MD2.o
unable to execute '/home/luanvv/Source/capcloud_01/30_implementation/31_source/CapCloudCommon/src/net/': Permission denied
error: command '/home/luanvv/Source/capcloud_01/30_implementation/31_source/CapCloudCommon/src/net/' failed with exit status 1
```

I don't know reason but may be I configure somewhere, because **/home/luanvv/Source/capcloud_01/30_implementation/31_source/CapCloudCommon/src/net/** is my java project and It's not relate anything. 
Don't know why it use that directory instead of **x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc** command.

Comment: Did you define a variable called `$CC` related to your java project by any chance?

Comment: LOL. Exactly what I did. You save my day. Thank you so much.